# Как в MATLAB написать алгоритм, чтоб он определял на картинке число лучиков, идущих из центра?

Tags: matlab

Пример картинки с белыми лучами:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант №1:**

1. преобразовать это изображение в
       бинарное: 1 - белые, 0 - черные.
2. найти координаты всех нулевых пикселей
3. преобразовать эти координаты из декартовых координат x,y в полярные         PHI(угол), RHO(расстояние от центра)
4. задать радиус окружности (произвольный)
5. выбрать пиксели, для которых RHO = R
6. можно обратно преобразовать в декартовы и представить в виде бинарной картинки - это будет пунктирная окружность. на ней нужно посчитать количество пунктиров.

   - выполнить разметку связных компонент и посчитать их количество

**вариант №2.**

1. найти центр откуда выходят эти лучи.
2. преобразовать картинку в бинарную: 1 - белый, 0 - черный.
3. задать окружность некоторого радиуса в найденном центре
4. все точки внутри окружности закрасить в белый (1) - этот шаг нужен для того чтобы убрать центральную область где лучи близко, т.к. из-за нее разметка связных компонент может работать не точно. Это даёт гарантию того что пиксели соседних лучей не являются смежными.
5. выполнить разметку связных компонент и посчитать их количество.